# Problem adding library in the Arduino IDE

Tags: esp32, library, opencv

Currently, I'm trying to build image processing on ESP32 using OpenCV GitHub - [joachimBurket/esp32-opencv: Shrinked OpenCV for ESP32](https://github.com/joachimBurket/esp32-opencv). Then I want to put this library into Arduino IDE.

But, I'm having problem `"Specified folder/zip file does not contain a valid library"`.  Is there a file that must be deleted to be included in the Arduino IDE libraries? And, I previously also tried manual input. But, not everything was detected by the Arduino IDE.

Please give me a way out as I am new in this field.

Comment: it is not an Arduino library

Comment: As Juraj wrote, this is not an Arduino library. It is meant to be compiled directly with the esp-idf toolchain, outside of the Arduino framework. To use it you would first have to port it to the Arduino framework, which is probably rather tedious.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. what if i change or adapt to the arduino libraries and manually input to arduino ide libraries, is it possible?